# What is the cheapest way to get from Amsterdam Schipol to Park&Ride (P&R) coach park at Zuiderzeeweg (Megabus Stop)

Tags: budget, public-transport, amsterdam, ams

I'm looking for the cheapest way to go from Amsterdam Schipol to Zeeburg Park&Ride (P&R) coach park at Zuiderzeeweg (postcode: 1095 KJ)

I also would like to find this exactly place (where I'll take the bus from megabus) on Google Maps, but I can't find it by typing: "Zeeburg Park&Ride (P&R) coach park at Zuiderzeeweg".

So, if you can, aswer these questions:

1) How can I go from Schipol to Megabus Stop (Zeeburg Park&Ride (P&R) coach park at Zuiderzeeweg)

2) How much I'll spend by public transport for this route.

3) Can you send the Google Map coordinates to see this Megabus Stop?

Have in mind that I don't have OV-chip card and I'll not buy one because I will stay for only 1 day in Amsterdam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start with your first question. Zeeburg Park&Ride seems to be located [here](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Zuiderzeeweg+46B,+1095+KJ+Amsterdam,+Netherlands/@52.3721278,4.9593543,179m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47c6093af848969f:0x85e551fdcffbcdf4?hl=en). I haven't actually been there, but if you look around the area with Street View, you will find a sign telling you that it is indeed Zeeburg P&R.

You can use this [online tool](http://maps.gvb.nl/en) to calculate the different routes to get there. It being a Park&Ride, it is just next to a station. The station name is Zuiderzeeweg/Piet Heintunnel.

As @EugenMartynow pointed out in the comments, if you take the route via Amsterdam Centraal, the train ticket will cost you 5.10 Euro (normal ticket price plus [1 Euro surcharge for single-use ticket](http://www.ns.nl/en/travellers/arrange-and-buy/tickets-and-passes/ticket-and-pass-types/single-and-return.html)) plus 2.90 Euro for a [one hour ticket](http://en.gvb.nl/gvb-1-uur) for the tram/bus.

Comment: Bus stops on the parking. Your google maps point is correct in a range of several meters. You're right that price is only for OV-card owners. For other travellers it will be more pricy - train will cost 5.10 for train with one way NS card (more info here http://www.ns.nl/en/travellers/arrange-and-buy/tickets-and-passes/ticket-and-pass-types/single-and-return.html and here http://www.ns.nl). Plus 2.90 with 1 hour card for OV public transport (more information here http://en.gvb.nl/gvb-1-uur). Can you update answer?

Comment: Thank you for all answers!! When I use the planning route tool I've to put "From: Schipol" and "To: ??" thank you!!

Comment: For future readers, for any location within the Netherlands you can use the OV9292 site, also available in English. http://9292.nl/en